# Arrangement of elements in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

There's an xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/password"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:hint="@string/loginText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:hint="@string/passwordText"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

When I run the program I get the following error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: asus.example.com.oop, PID: 5020
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Circular dependencies cannot exist in RelativeLayout

What's the matter? Login is above password, password is above button. I don't understand why there's a circular dependence

Comment: It means you are aligned both view left to right & right to left so remove the dependency alignment..

Comment: can you try a clean build. I don't see a circular dependency here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**

Instead of having the `layout_above` it'll be a good option to use `layout_below`:

Like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:hint="Hello"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/login"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hello"
        android:layout_below="@+id/password"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Try it, Hope it helps.

Comment: yes, it works, but what's the diffrence? Why layout_above doesn't work?

Comment: @SergeiMikhailovskii Your code does work in my system without errors. For you, try adding this line in your button `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` and check